# How to identify a postback from page refresh (F5), and not from a button press?

Tags: jsf

I'm using a `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.listener()}"/>` event. It's triggered both on page reload (F5), and when a press a button on the page (that renders a table).

```
                    <a4j:commandButton
                        value="rerender"
                        action="#{bean.updateTable()}"
                        render="myTable" />
```

I need to call the listener only on page refresh (F5), not when the button is pressed.

Is there a way?

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()` will not solve, because the button is also a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the listener to be called, but inside the listener you can check that the request is not a post and is not an AJAX request.

Look this:
[How to differentiate Ajax requests from normal Http requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885893/how-to-differentiate-ajax-requests-from-normal-http-requests)

And also you can know the request method :

```
request.getMethod()
```

If  it's not an ajax and it's a GET, then the page has been requested by the first time, or refreshed with F5.

Comment: Maybe also refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687910/how-to-avoid-prerenderview-method-call-in-ajax-request (actually current question is the reverse of the one I refer to here, only for newer versions of jsf)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can entirely avoid calling the listener. I think it's part of the JSF spec.

You could work around it though. Add an event to the button click (`onclick` I guess) that sets a hidden variable `buttonClicked`. In your listener, check for the variable. If it's set, return immediately. The listener code should still run on a normal refresh but not when you click the button.